# Для чего нужны параметры в функциях?

Tags: javascript

Начинаю изучать JavaScript и столкнулся с непониманием , где -то пропустил видимо отрывок и не понимаю для чего писать все это в скобках ? (value,index,array)

```
function myFunction(value, index, array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Это переменные, которые Вы можете передать в функцию и взаимодействовать с ними внутри неё.
[Здесь очень хорошо про это сказано](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics)

Пример с умножением всех числовых данных из массива на два (из комментариев) - Вы сами должны указывать что хотите передать в функцию, что сделать с этими данными и что возвращать. Аргументы функции ни к чему не привязаны.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,8, "try out!"];

function increase(array, factor) {
    return array.map(e => Number.isInteger(e) ? e * factor : e);
}

console.log(increase(array, 2));
```

Comment: да спасибо я понял , просто объяснение на сайте не очень было , мне например нужно сделать, чтобы каждое мое значение в массиве умножилось на 2 и вывелось по порядка  , а там показано что нужно прописывать value index array , когда я могу просто написать value и умножить на 2 и  получить то что нужно

Comment: Вы сами задаёте параметры функции. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо не знал про этот сайт , предпочитаю w3school

Comment: На Лёрне, мне кажется, всё доступнее.

Comment: я вот только не пойму , почему ты пишешь в скобках (array,factor) тут какая то последовательность этих опций должна ? И откуда они вообще берутся

Comment: Нет, я же дополнил ответ - они ни к чему не привязаны. Вы сами задаёте имена аргументов и их последовательность. Можно даже не задавать и пользоваться псевдомассивом аргументов (https://learn.javascript.ru/arguments-pseudoarray), но в этом чаще всего нет необходимости, и в стрелочных функциях массива `arguments` нет.

Comment: `а там показано что нужно прописывать` не нужно, а можно. Там показано лишь с какими параметрами будет вызвана функция обратного вызова. Использовать ли их все и как их назвать - ваше дело.

Comment: @vp_arth не смог по-человечески сформулировать, каюс. Спасибо ;)

Answer (score 0):

Это параметры функций для обработки их внутри функции.

К примеру, у вас есть функция складывающая два числа. Что бы функция работала именно над этими числами, вы должны передать их в функцию:

```
function myFunction(a, b){
   return a+b;
}

с = myFunction(2, 2);
```

Подробнее с описаниями и примерами здесь: [Функции - Параметры](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Answer (score 0):

Это аргументы функции - локальные переменные, которые отражают параметры, с которыми функция вызывается.
Только автор функции определяет, сколько и каких аргументов должно быть указано в функции.

```js
function a(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

// Доступ к аргументам можно получить также через специальный объект arguments
function b() {
  var arg1 = arguments[0];
  var arg2 = arguments[1];
  var arg3 = arguments[2]; // undefined, потому что передали всего 2 аргумента

  console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3, arguments.length);
}
// В новых версиях js есть также очень удобный оператор rest:
function mulBy(factor, ...args) {
  return args.map(a => a*factor);
}

a(12, 23);
b(34, 45);

console.log(mulBy(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```